# What is the OAuth flow to generate access token without consent from resource owner?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, openid-connect, rfc6749

<sup>Roles and terminology used in this question are the same as [RFC 6749](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-1.1).</sup>

### Description of the use-case

I want to allow a trusted OAuth *client* to ask *authorization server* to issue an access token **on behalf** of the *resource owner* **without his consent** (and without involving neither him nor his agent in the flow).

### Investigations

As far as I know, there is not any grant matching this flow in [RFC 6749, Section 4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4):

| Grant | Suitable | Why |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Authorization Code Grant [RFC 6749, Section 4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1) | No | It involves both *Resource Owner* and *User-Agent*. |
| Implicit Grant [RFC 6749, Section 4.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.2) | No | It also involves both *Resource Owner* and *User-Agent*. |
| Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant [RFC 6749, Section 4.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.3) | No | It might work if we knew the password of the resource owner, but we don't. |
| Client Credentials Grant [RFC 6749, Section 4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4) | No, but.. | It doesn't involve the *Resource Owner* or his *User-Agent* but it's not granting access on behalf of a user. |
| Token Exchange [RFC 8693, Section 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693#section-2) | No, but.. | It requires an initial token (named `subject_token`) which doesn't exist in my scenario. |

#### Client Credentials

The *Client Credentials* grant is promising because it allows a *client* to access protected resources owned by a *resource owner* without involving him. Although, in my understanding, it's not on behalf of the *resource owner*. Quoting the [RFC 6749, Section 4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.4):

> The client can request an access token using only its client credentials (...) when the client is requesting access to the protected resources under its control, or those of another resource owner that have been previously arranged with the authorization server (...).

Therefore, with access token returned by *Client Credentials* grant, it is for instance impossible to assign a *sub* claim value as defined in [RFC 7662, Section 2.2: *OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection > Introspection Response*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662#section-2.2) (cf. [RFC 7519, Section 4.1.2: *JWT*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.2) ).

#### Token Exchange

<sup>This grant has been suggested by @Kaankom. [See @Kaankom 's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70120446/2437450)</sup>

The [RFC 8693](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693) defines how to obtain a security token employing impersonation and delegation. It sounds like the perfect grant for my use-case but this grant requires as input a `subject_token` parameter which *"represents the identity of the acting party."* The RFC says:

> Typically, this will be the party that is authorized to use the requested security token and act on behalf of the subject.

I don't have this token. However, I could maybe forge a new one (see Solution 5).

### Non-standard solutions

#### Solution 1: A new OAuth grant

[RFC 6749, Section 4.5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.5) allow us to implement a new grant type. Similar to *Client Credentials*, this brand new grant would REQUIRE an additional parameter in his *Access Token Request*. This parameter would define the *resource owner* identifier for which the *client* will act on behalf of the *resource owner*.

#### Solution 2: Tweak the *Client Credentials* grant

Instead of implementing a new OAuth grant (cf. solution 1), we could instead add an optional parameter in existing *Client Credentials* grant. If specified, the *authorization server* should validate that the *client* is allowed to act on behalf of the requested *resource owner* (specified by the new parameter).

#### Solution 3: Tweak the *Authorization Code* grant

Using the *Authorization Code* grant, we could bypass steps A, B and C as defined in [RFC 6749, Section 4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1) and let the *client* request an access token without having to add a `code` or a `redirect_uri` but with its client credentials **and** an additional parameter which define the *resource owner*.

#### Solution 4: Implement it out of OAuth

Browsing *the* internet, you might find implementations which are bypassing the OAuth mechanism and its `access_token`. For instance, in article [*"How to Convert from APIKey to OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials"*](https://developer.byu.edu/blog/how-convert-apikey-oauth-20-client-credentials), they are using an extra HTTP header `Acting-For` on *resource server* calls.

#### Solution 5: *Token Exchange* grant with self-forged token

The *Token Exchange* grant requires a `subject_token` but (as far as I know) it doesn't define the policy that the *authorization server* SHOULD apply based on this token. Therefore, it would be theorically possible for the *client* to forge an unsigned JWT with the target *subject* (`sub` claim) and obtain a signed JWT in return. It looks promising but requires more investigation.

#### Notes

I intentionally not named the parameter used in solution 1, 2 and 3. However [OpenID Connect Core 1.0, Section 3.1.2.1/Section 4](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) is defining an optional parameter named `login_hint` which *"hint to the Authorization Server about the login identifier the End-User might use to log in"*. However `sub` might be another good proposal.

Comment: Well, I guess Solution 1 remains "standard"...

Comment: I added the proposal from Kaankom based on RFC 8693. It looks promising but requires more investigation

Answer (score 2):

The Use Case you described sounds like impersonation.

Take a look at this: [RFC 8693 - Token Exchange](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693)

Comment: Thanks @Kaankom , indeed, it looks like "impersonation", but it's not feasible to use RFC 8693 grant because it requires as input the subject_token which in my scenario doesn't exist.
Btw, the subject_token "represents the identity of the party on behalf  of whom the request is being made" (quoting the RFC) which is actually what I try to do.

I'm gonna add this grant in the list in my question. Many thanks for your input !

Comment: Here it is. I added a 5th solution in the question which is related to your proposal. The idea would be to use the token exchange grant with, as subject_token, a token forged by the client. I have to do a few tests before confirming that it works !

Answer (score 0):

You've not really described the use case / requirement, though I will describe something that may be in line with your use case and give you some ideas. Perhaps thinking more in terms of claims and API aauthorization will solve your problem in a standard way?

**CORPORATE ASSETS USE CASE**

Sometimes the assets don't belong to the end user and an entity has permissions to operate on a subset of users:

- An investment bank may be able to update certain details for its employees in a wider trading system
- A doctor's surgery may be able to update medical details for its patients in a system that contains nationwide data

In OAuth terms the bank / surgery would use the client credentials grant, and be identified by either a client ID or possibly a custom claim in the token issued.

If bank A tried to use their access token to update details for a trader at bank B, it would fail API authorization and they would receive an HTTP response with status 404, meaning `data not found for caller`.

It would not be natural though for bank A to get an access token for `Jane Doe` when updating that record, since that is not the caller identity. At an auditing level:

- The Authorization Server would indicate that a token was issued to bank A
- The API would indicate that the record for Jane Doe was updated by bank A.

The API could have many intricate domain specific rules around which type of data updates are allowed. These are usually managed in the API logic, while the access token contains only key caller identity information that the API can digitally trust before applying rules.

For more on this topic see our [Claims Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) article.

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

The following answer describes the flow, grant and parameters that may be used to allow a trusted OAuth *client* to obtain an `access_token` without the prior *resource owner* consent. This method is using the *Token Exchange* grant (defined in [RFC 8693](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693)) in an impersonation scenario where the *client* would have to forge an unsecured `subject_token` and exchange it for a secured `access_token`. This method assumes that the *authorization server* produces and consumes JWT ([RFC 7519](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519)). It would not work with opaque token.

### Sequence Diagram

[image: Sequence Diagram to allow a trusted client obtain access_token without resource owner consent thanks to token exchange grant]

#### Step 1: Forge the initial JWT

In this first step, the client forges an initial [unsecured JWT token (RFC 7519, Section 6)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-6). This JWT MUST contain at least the subject (`sub`) claim with, as value, the *resource owner* or another *subject* that the client want to impersonate.

#### Step 2: The *client* requests to exchange the initial unsecured JWT for a secured access token

The *client* exchanges the JWT forged in step 1 for a secured *access token*. According to [RFC 8693 Section 2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693#section-2.1), the *client* sends a *Token Exchange request* with the following headers/parameters:

- the `Authorization` header contains the *client* credentials (*client id* and *client secret*), following the *Basic Authentication* scheme.
- the body parameter `grant_type` specify the grant type we want to use: `token_exchange`
- the body parameter `subject_token` contains the JWT forged in step 1
- the body parameter `subject_token_type` specify the subject token type we forged: an `access_token` (which is actually a JWT)

This is the bare minimum that the client MUST send. Although it SHOULD probably specify the `audience`, the target `resource` server and the list of `scope`.

#### Step 3: The *authorization server* returns the access token

According to its policy, the *authorization server* identifies the *client* as trusted and therefore allows to generate an `access_token` with unsecured `subject_token` in input. The *subject* defined in the `subject_token` (`sub` claim) is recycle in the generated `access_token`.

The *authorization server* will also add an *Actor claim* (`act`) according to [RFC 8693, Section 4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693#section-4.1). The value of this claim is a JSON object with another `sub` key and the *client id* as value.

#### Step 4: The *client* requests a *resource*

In this example, the *client* requests a "personal" *resource* (`/my/resource`) with the *access token*. The `sub` claim inside the JWT is used to identify the "my" aka the *subject*.

#### Step 5: The *resource* is returned with an impersonation of the *subject*

That's it.

### Disclaimer

I never implemented or tested this solution. It obviously requires a few changes in your *authorization server* and its policy. No security audit has been performed. Be careful with this flow. Confirmation from OAuth experts should be required prior to implementation.

Comment: @kaankom thanks again for you answer. It was really useful to design this solution.